# Httphandler returing an array

Tags: c#, asp.net, httphandler

Can a httphandler in .net return a value? If yes how?

Thanks,

Subrat

Answer (score 2):

The [`IHttpHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.processrequest.aspx) interface only implements two things:

```
Boolean IsReusable {get;}

void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context);
```

So no... in the strictest sense it is not meant to return a value. Now, you can shape your [response](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.aspx) to look however you want it to (SOAP/XML/JSON). So in effect, you can return anything your heart desires so long as HTTP can support it, and the client consuming it knows how to deal with it.

However, it is ill-advised to go about trying to implement your own services via an `HttpHandler` as there are [simpler and more efficient ways](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx) to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

The `HttpHandler` responses by its `ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)` method, in which you can modify the parameter `context` to tell what do you want to send back as an response. `context.Response.ContentType` specifies the MIME type of the response,for example the reponse is `text/html` so the browser will render it to an html page.Or the reponse is `video/mp4` the browser will try to open it and in most circumstances the browser will show a download dialog. Unfortunately there is no `text/array` in the MIME type(and i think there won't be in the future). But you can pass your array value as plain text with special formats and deserialize it at client side. Here is a simple example:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    context.Response.Write("[1,2,3,4]");
}
```

and at client side in javascript:

```
var response = GetTheResponse(); //maybe via ajax or something equivalent.
var myArray = eval(response);    //myArray[0]=1,myArray[1]=2...
```

In a real project, you may want to get an array with complex objects in it(not just simple numbers). So you need systematized serialization/deserialization standards, for example, you serialize your array of `Person` object into json strings and write it to the reponse, and you deserialize them back at client side using some json utils.